# Auto generated class reference links on mainpage in doxygen

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm trying to generate documentation for a C# application using doxygen. Right now, I'm trying to create a mainpage that has some links to the central classes of the documented application.

I've created the page using markdown and it looks something like this:

```
\mainpage
Project name
==================
bla
Important classes
------------------
* Class1
* Class2
* Class3
```

For some reason, doxygen doesn't automatically generate links to the corresponding classes on this page. To makes things strange, doxygen has no problem recognizing these class names inside the code documentation, and generating the corresponding links, so, as far as I can tell, it's a mainpage problem.

Is there any way to do it, without using hardcoded links to the generated class pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been experimenting as I've a similar need - I've a mainpage written in Markdown too.  This is essentially the same answer as Stephen's but with a bit more info.  I'm using doxygen 1.8.5.

**With AUTOLINK_SUPPPORT set to NO in the doxyfile:**

It seems you need the *fully qualified* package name

`com.bigcorp.stuff.product.namespace.ClassName`

And you also need a reference command to make the link:

`\ref com.bigcorp.stuff.product.namespace.ClassName`

which does at least mean you can qualify the output text

`\ref com.bigcorp.stuff.product.namespace.ClassName "ClassName"`

means the output text doesn't have the namespace clutter.

**With AUTOLINK_SUPPPORT set to YES (or blank):**

You don't *need* the `\ref` i.e. `com.bigcorp.stuff.product.namespace.ClassName` will provide a link to the class just by itself, but does have the clutter so using a `\ref` might be cleaner anyway.

Just using `ClassName` still doesn't provide a link.  Seems you need the package preamble.

Curiously, hovering over an automatically created link produces a pop-up description of the target class.  However, an explicit `\ref` link does not.

Comment: Good explanation. It is strange that HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES does not work in this case, but it doesn't - I have tried.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it! Prefixing the class name with the namespace name like `Namespace1.Class1` did the trick!

This is still strange, as doxygen has no problem handling short class names in other places, but hey, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found how you can avoid adding a tedious \ref on each class and keep the class tooltip.

You can simply put your comment inside of the namespace.

```
namespace com.bigcorp.stuff.product.namespace
{
/// \page page_name Page Name
/// This is a working class auto ref -> ClassName.
}
```

This won't work for classes in multiple namespaces though...